# Help with authorization and redirection decorator in python (pylons)

Tags: python, redirect, pylons, decorator

I'm trying to write a simple decorator to check the authentication of a user, and to redirect to the login page if s/he is not authenticated:

```
def authenticate(f):
    try:
        if user['authenticated'] is True:
            return f
    except:
        redirect_to(controller='login', action='index')

class IndexController(BaseController):
    @authenticate
    def index(self):
        return render('/index.mako' )
```

But this approach doesn't work.  When a user is authenticated, everything is fine.  But when the user is not authenticated, redirect_to() doesn't work and I am given this error:

```
HTTPFound: 302 Found Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 0 location: /login
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i don't know pylons, but it seems the way you wrote your decorator is not good.

a decorator is a callable which must **return a callable**. the decorator is called at the moment the function is defined, and it should return a callable (generally a function) which will be called in place of the function being decorated.

in your sample, your decorator returns a callable only if the user is authenticated *at the moment the `index()` function is defined*.

try rewriting it this way:

```
def authenticate(func):
    def call(*args, **kwargs):
        if user['authenticated'] is True:
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect_to(controller='login', action='index')
    return call
```

here, `authenticate()` defines an inner function, which is returned in place of the function it decorates. now when you decorate a function using this decorator:

```
@authenticate
def index(self):
    return render('/index.mako' )
```

this means that each time you call `index()`, you are in fact calling the inner function declared in your decorator.

you should note that: due to the way functions are defined in python, the function object returned by the decorator still remembers the value of arguments of the function in which it was defined. `call()` still knows about the argument `func` which was passed when the decorator was called. (this is called a closure)

decorators are difficult to understand although they are not complicated. you should search google for a tutorial on decorators: there are plenty of them which gives a very nice understanding of the concept, far much clearer than the python documentation.

Comment: This was so helpful.  Thank you very much!